# Enter SQLite data if not exists

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to create a database with some records in it (if these don't exists yet). I now have the following code:

```
db = openOrCreateDatabase("DBNAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tablename(id VARCHAR, name VARCHAR, active VARCHAR);");
db.execSQL("insert into tablename(id, name, active) VALUES ('1','name1','0');");
db.execSQL("insert into tablename(id, name, active) VALUES ('2','name2','1');");
```

What am I missing for inserting the data (if this doesn't exists yet)?

Comment: Consider using `SQLiteOpenHelper` to manage your database.

Comment: I find it useful to use `REPLACE INTO` instead of `INSERT INTO`. It inserts the missing data or updates the existing one. So you won't have duplicates.

Comment: You're not missing anything right now. Data should be inserted.